# Secondary mysql instance runs but mysqld_multi reports it is "not running"

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqld-multi

On my Ubuntu server, there are two mysql instances running at the same time.

- A default, normal mysql instance
- A secondary mysql instance running with `mysqld_multi`.

The command `sudo service mysql status` correctly states the mysql service is active.

I want to check the secondary instance's status so I use this command :

```
sudo mysqld_multi report
```

...and I get :

```
MySQL server from group: mysqld1 is not running
```

which seems pretty inconsistent since I can connect to this mysql instance from my DB client.

**Why does `mysqld_multi` tell me the instance is not running ?**

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the support of mysql_multi was dropped long ago.  The popular way to do it today is with Docker.

Comment: @RickJames I haven't seen anything about an end of support. Mysqld_multi is still provided with mysql 8 and I see no warning in documentation.
I'd have liked to use docker but I couldn't at the time I made this...

Answer (score 1):

Check creation mysql instance dir, confirm mysql rights and install instance in dir

```
mkdir -p /u01/data/mysql/mysql1 && chown mysql:mysql /u01/data/mysql /u01/data/mysql/mysql1
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/u01/data/mysql/mysqld1
```